# Change of RootFolder in .conf file has no effect - apache2.4 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2.4

I have the impression that my changes in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` does not result in any effect.

I changed the document root from:
`DocumentRoot /var/www/html`
to
`DocumentRoot /var/www/html3`
(which does not exist) 
in the hope of getting a "not found" error in the web browser. Instead, I can still see the home page of the file index.html

Why is it??

On the other hand, if I change the name of the folder to something different than html (say htmlx) I get the "not found".

(after every change to the .conf file I run `service apache2 reload`)

Comment: Did you restart apache after changes?

Comment: yes, with `service apache2 reload`

Comment: I've seen another question just like this here. I think there may be a bug with it. Maybe try to file a bug and see if they come out with a fix.

Comment: Could you post 000-default.conf on http://pastebin.com/?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/u7KCY0um it is just the default, the only thing I change was the folder name in /var/www

Comment: @GeorgeLongIsland I have this very exact problem. Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache 2.4.7. Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo service apache2 restart`.

When making changes to 000-default.conf (and any other host configuration file in /etc/apache2/sites-available) you need to use `sudo service apache2 restart` to load the new configuration. `service apache2 reload` would not actually reload the configuration.
Remember to edit `/etc/hosts` for the url you want to see in the browser.